# How do I interpret prediction interval and point prediction?

Tags: predictive-models, interpretation, prediction-interval, interpolation

Consider a simple linear model: I have obtained a prediction interval of $(37, 66)$ and a point prediction of $52$. (the problem behind is not a concern I reckon, for the sake of the question).

Now I know that if the actual response will be $\geq 50$, then a plant will grow, whereas if it is less than $50$, it will fail to grow.

The question is to interpret the prediction interval (and the point prediction I guess), to understand whether there is evidence that the plant will not grow.

> How do I go about interpreting this?

For example the upper end of the interval of prediction is bigger than $50$, and also the predicted value is slightly bigger than $50$, however the lower end of the prediction interval goes as far down as $37$.. so how does a statistician interpret this? Is there evidence? And if I need to use some mathematical tools, what techniques should I use to see if there is evidence?

Comment: So do you want to predict whether or not the plant will grow?  What confidence level did you choose to get the interval (37, 66)? Explaining the linear model can be important because knowing the error distribution could  help with the inference.  Please edit your question to address my questions.  Otherwise it could be put on hold.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I will edit it soon! Anyway the level was 95% confidence/prediction interval! And I dont want to predict. I have already evaluated the prediction interval and the point-prediction for the response $y_o$  of a new observation, call it $x_0$. Now my question is about the interpretation. Say a biologist then ask me: okay you have found a prediction and a prediction interval. But is there a strong evidence (or moderate or weak) that the plant will not grow? ( i.e. the response is less than $50$?)